# Creating account using accounts-password in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to create account in project created using meteor-boilerplate.I am trying to create it from client. When I hit create account, error comes "signups forbidden". I can still log in using the credentials present in db. I'm using accounts-password, accounts-UI, Will anyone tell me solution...

Comment: Can you give us some of the code you have written so far? The more details, the easier for us to give you an answer.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me when conflicting account packages were present at the same time. I solved it by doing

```
meteor remove useraccounts:bootstrap
```

In your case, it may be accounts-ui or something else that needs to be removed.

Comment: For my case, useraccounts:materialize was annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Your project has disabled signup from the client side.

Look for this in your code somewhere

```
Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation : true
});
```

and set `forbidClientAccountCreation` to `false`.

Comment: I also tried with setting forbidClientAccountCreation to false  but still same error comes "signups forbidden". I will tell more about it, I have created file structure using  https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-boilerplate and after resetting it, I'm using accounts-password code for creating account.